# Linear programming with scipy.optimize.linprog

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've just check the simple linear programming problem with scipy.optimize.linprog:

```
1*x[1] + 2x[2] -> max

1*x[1] + 0*x[2] <= 5
0*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 5
1*x[1] + 0*x[2] >= 1
0*x[1] + 1*x[2] >= 1
1*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 6
```

And got the very strange result, I expected that x[1] will be 1 and x[2] will be 5, but:

```
>>> print optimize.linprog([1, 2], A_ub=[[1, 1]], b_ub=[6], bounds=(1, 5), method='simplex')
  status: 0
   slack: array([ 4.,  4.,  4.,  0.,  0.])
 success: True
     fun: 3.0
       x: array([ 1.,  1.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 2
```

Can anyone explain, why I got this strange result?

Comment: Well, it's not that strange anymore once you realize that `linprog` actually minimizes :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`optimize.linprog` always minimizes your target function. If you want to maximize instead, you can use that `max(f(x)) == -min(-f(x))`

```
from scipy import optimize

optimize.linprog(
    c = [-1, -2], 
    A_ub=[[1, 1]], 
    b_ub=[6],
    bounds=(1, 5),
    method='simplex'
)
```

This will give you your expected result, with the value `-f(x) = -11.0`

```
 slack: array([ 0.,  4.,  0.,  4.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 3
       x: array([ 1.,  5.])
  status: 0
 success: True
     fun: -11.0
```