# Solving a tableau and/or automating the simplex method using Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use `optimize.linprog()` with python to solve a series of equations instead of manually performing calculations with the simplex method and a tableau.  My peers and I are really just trying to automate the process of solving a tableau with python to optimize an equation series through either maximization or minimization.

This code is a modified version of code at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog

The code appears to work great for the example given:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy
from numpy import *
from scipy import optimize

# Minimize: f = -x + 4y
# -3x+y<=6
# x + 2y <= 4
# y >= -3
c = [-1, 4]
A = [[-3, 1], [1, 2]]
b = [6, 4]
x_bounds = (None, None)
y_bounds = (-3, None)
res = optimize.linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x_bounds, y_bounds), options={"disp": False})
print(res)
```

However when I plug in numbers for other systems the array appears with zeros.  Here is one sample that I have tried which does not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy
from numpy import *
from scipy import optimize

# Equations
# x+y <= 40
# 6x + 12y <= 312
# 40x+120y <= 2400

# Bounds
#  x >=0
#  y >=0

# Objective Function:
# f=100x+250y

c = [100, 250]
A = [[1, 1], [6, 12],[40,120]]
b = [40, 312, 2400]
x_bounds = (0, None)
y_bounds = (0, None)
res = optimize.linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x_bounds, y_bounds), options={"disp": False})
print(res)
```

I know from solving this second equation series using the simplex method and a tableau that it solves to x=28, y=12, s2=848.
Check:
28+12=40

```
4(28)+12(120)+848=2400
6(28)+12(12)=312
100(28)+250(12)=5800
```

The tableau being solved is:

```
x      y      s1     s2     s3     z      
1      1      1      0      0      0      40
4      120    0      1      0      0      2400
6      12     0      0      1      0      312
-100   250    0      0      0      1      0
```

Does anybody know how to solve optimization problems or tableaus with python?  Is it possible to fix the code above?  My peers and I have been looking at this all week.  We have seen many links and snippets but nobody has been able to make it work.  If you have a sample of working python code could you please show it in its entirety?

Comment: Without having checked your question in detail: You didn't mention if you want to maximize or minimize. `linprog` always minimizes. My answer here may already be the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849883/linear-programming-with-scipy-optimize-linprog/30850123#30850123

Comment: Thank you so much. That looks great...could you show how I could maximize and how I can print out the detail?  I ran your code and it did not throw errors but it did not show output.  I am not sure where to place the maximize parameter.

Comment: The key idea is in the very first sentence of my answer: you don't need a parameter, because you can easily transform between maximization and minimization by multiplying your weights by `-1`

Comment: Very nice. I can see how that works.  The code worked if I changed [100, 250] to [-100, -250]. Fantastic.  I have a follow up question but I think the issue I am having may be due to the way I set up my equations.Thank you very much!!