# Python: elegant visualisation for feasible area & objective function of LP in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-programming

I want to learn to plot the following LP problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849883/linear-programming-with-scipy-optimize-linprog) elegantly with matplotlib

```
1*x[1] + 2x[2] -> max

1*x[1] + 0*x[2] <= 5
0*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 5
1*x[1] + 0*x[2] >= 1
0*x[1] + 1*x[2] >= 1
1*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 6
```

where the first line is the objective function and the rest are the constraints of an LP problem.

I already found a demo [here](http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-1/) that I tweaked little bit but how to do this elegantly? How to fill the upper triangle in the picture with grey with the lines (not functions like in the demo)?

**How to visualise the objective function and the feasible area of a LP (linear programming) problem elegantly in Matplotlib of Python?**

---

*Code*

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#I hold x a line while defining new values for each y
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
#1*x[1] + 0*x[2] <= 5
#y0*0=5-x  #No initialization with respect to y0 because it is zero.
#0*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 5
y1=5+x*0
#1*x[1] + 0*x[2] >= 1
#y2*0=1-x  #No inititialization
#0*x[1] + 1*x[2] >= 1
y3=1-x*0
#1*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 6
y4=6-x
#TODO: HOW TO DRAW THE ABOVE LINEAR EQUATIONS ELEGANTLY in matplotlib?
#Drawing the lines by end points because of the zeroes.
plt.plot(x,y4,label=r'$x[1]+x[2]<=6$')
plt.plot([5,5],[10,-10])       #x  <  5
plt.plot([10,-2],[5,5])        #y2 <  5
plt.plot([1,1],[10,-10], 'r-') #x  >= 1 
plt.plot([10,-2],[1,1],'b--')  #y3 >= 1
#TODO: how to fill the upper triangle only?
# http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-1/
#plt.fill_between(x, y5, y6, where=y5>y6, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following, where `x` and `y{i}` are used where possible.

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#I hold x a line while defining new values for each y
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
#1*x[1] + 0*x[2] <= 5
#y0*0=5-x  #No initialization with respect to y0 because it is zero.
#0*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 5
y1=5+x*0
#1*x[1] + 0*x[2] >= 1
#y2*0=1-x  #No inititialization
#0*x[1] + 1*x[2] >= 1
y3=1-x*0
#1*x[1] + 1*x[2] <= 6
y4=6-x

plt.plot(x,y4,label=r'$x[1]+x[2]<=6$')
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.axvline(5, color='g')        #y2 <  5
plt.axvline(1, color='r') #x  >= 1 
plt.plot(x,y3,'b--')  #y3 >= 1

plt.fill_between(x, y1, y4, where=(x>1)&(x<5), color='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I think any implementation in matplotlib will require to manually solve the respective inequality for either x or y and then do the according plot.

Comment: Can you understand why the label `label=r'$x[1]+x[2]<=6$')` is not there? Ofc I forgot `plt.legend()`, thank you.

Comment: As in the linked code, you would need to ask for a legend. They use `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)`, which is fine, also just `plt.legend()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using [GrUMPy](https://github.com/coin-or/GrUMPy). It's not too straightforward to set up and use, though.